# Random answers when dealing with lists in OCaml

Tags: list, recursion, ocaml

I'm trying to make a function that gets me the number of alive cells in a game of life.
The goal is to look into an int list list, and, given the coordinates of a cell, return the number of alive cells next to it.
The problem is that my function seems to answer completely at random, and i don't see what can cause this in the code
**This is a class assignment, so I'm not asking for a specific answer, just for a hint as to where the problem might lie**

here's my code :

```
(* nth : reimplementation of List.nth that returns 0 if there is no such
 * element
 * [int list -> int -> int] *)

 let rec nth l n =
    match l with
        | [] -> 0
        | a::l -> if n = 0 
            then a 
            else nth l (n-1);;

(* get_cell : given a couple of coordinates, returns the value at the
 * coordinates on the matrix 
 * [int * int -> int list list -> int] *)

let rec get_cell (x,y) matrix = 
    match (List.nth matrix y) with
        | [] -> empty
        | l  -> nth l x;;

(* count_neighbours : given a couple of coordinates and a matrix, returns the 
 * number of alive cells in the neighborhood of the designed cell 
 * [int * int -> int list list -> int] *)

let count_neighbours (x,y) matrix =
    let neighbors = [ (x-1,y-1); (x-1,y); (x-1,y+1); 
                      (x,y-1); (x,y+1);
                      (x+1,y-1); (x+1,y); (x+1,y+1); ] in
    let rec aux = (function 
        | [] -> 0
        | h::t -> (get_cell h matrix) + aux (t)
    ) in
    aux neighbors;;
```

and here's an example session :

```
# let test_board = [[0; 1; 1; 1; 1]; [1; 0; 0; 0; 0]; [1; 0; 1; 0; 0]; [0; 1; 0; 0; 0];
   [0; 1; 1; 0; 1]];;
val test_board : int list list =
  [[0; 1; 1; 1; 1]; [1; 0; 0; 0; 0]; [1; 0; 1; 0; 0]; [0; 1; 0; 0; 0];
   [0; 1; 1; 0; 1]]
# count_neighbours (3,3) test_board;;
- : int = 3
# get_cell (2,2) test_board;;
- : int = 1
# get_cell (2,3) test_board;;
- : int = 0
# get_cell (2,4) test_board;;
- : int = 1
# get_cell (3,2) test_board;;
- : int = 0
# get_cell (3,4) test_board;;
- : int = 0
# get_cell (4,2) test_board;;
- : int = 0
# get_cell (4,3) test_board;;
- : int = 0
# get_cell (4,4) test_board;;
- : int = 1
```

As you can see, random results...
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, it's not completely *random*, unless you specify randomness. :-)

I'm pretty sure it's just a minor thing of using the right coordinates to getting your cell. Since you've mentioned that this is a homework assignment, I'll just point you towards getting the solution, than one rightaway.

What does `List.nth test_board x` give you? `x` being any of the numbers you entered above.

After doing some minor adjustments, mine gives me this result:

```
# get_cell (2,4) test_board;;
- : int = 0
# count_neighbours (3,3) test_board;;
- : int = 3
```

Good luck.

**EDIT** 
As for the `count_neighbours` implementation, it helps if you look at it as a list of lists as shown below.

Take your `test_board`, it looks something like this to the oCaml compiler:

```
    0  1  2  3  4
0  [0; 1; 1; 1; 1];
1  [1; 0; 0; 0; 0]; 
2  [1; 0; 1; 0; 0]; 
3  [0; 1; 0; **0**; 0];
4  [0; 1; 1; 0; 1];
```

I have highlighted the cell corresponding to `(3, 3)`. There are three `1`s shown there - top left, bottom left and bottom right.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but i'm confused :

    `# count_neighbours (3,3) test_board;;`

shouldn't return

    `- : int = 3`

but rather

    `- : int = 1`

if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: That's because there are 3 `1`s along the diagonals to the cell `(3,3)`. Look at your implementation of `count_neighbours` and how you build the `neighours` list. So, once you get all the `1`s, you're just adding them up.

Comment: I know about that, but I can't seem to find the three `1`s.
The diagonal is made of `000 010 100`
please correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like we're not looking at the same diagonal...

Comment: See my edit. In `(x, y)` - `x` stands for the rows and `y` stands for the columns. That said, in your implementation, you should probably also check for list bounds so that you don't accidentally look for elements that are not in list's range.

Comment: alright, i didn't get that the lists were numbered from 0 :)
thanks for your help!